# Как сортировать массив от большего к меньшему, в моём случает это строки

Tags: javascript

Нужно вывести строки с наибольшим количеством символов до наименьшего, вот мой пример. Он сортирует мне по алфавиту.

```js
let str = 'welcone to  Africa Vladysvav';

function changeWordsOrder(str) {
  const strWorsd = str.split(' ');
  strWorsd.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.length > b.length
  })
  console.log(strWorsd);
};
changeWordsOrder(str);
```

Comment: "Он сортирует мне по алфавиту." - но это не точно?

Comment: Безмерно благодарен!

Comment: Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function changeWordsOrder(str) {
  return str.split(' ').sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
}

const str = 'welcone to  Africa Vladysvav';
console.log(changeWordsOrder(str));
```